# Rails 4 how to validate has_many with unique column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

This is the example provided:

```
has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drivers, -> { where('name').distinct }
end
```

My scenario is not a has_many through, which is why I dropped the class_name: clause.

What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent a Driver from being loaded into a Vehicle's collection unless the Driver name is unique.

```
herbie = Vehicle.create(name: 'Herbie')
fred = Driver.create(name: 'Fred')

herbie.drivers << fred

herbie.drivers << fred # This second association should not work.
```

Comment: Why can't you use a uniqueness validation here. Like `validates_uniqueness_of :name` And also having uniqueness constraint on name is  a bad idea. What if two or more people has the same name 'Fred'?

Comment: In this particular situation names are permitted to be the same, but drivers with same name can't use the same car. It's just a contrived example in this case, but the logic applies to a real scenario I am working on with vehicle makes and models.

Comment: Can you post your `Driver` model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scope` option of uniqueness here.

In you `Driver` model, add the below

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :vehicle_id
```

Also you should add a migration like this:

```
add_index :drivers, [ :vehicle_id, :name ], :unique => true
```

to avoid race conditions. For more info, check [***this***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks. I'm assuming you are suggesting add_index in a migration.

Comment: Yes! add_index in a migration :)

Comment: @ClayMorton Please accept my answer by ticking it :)

Comment: Whoops sorry bout that!